# parentNode in Javascript doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: javascript, gridview, textbox, onkeyup

I use a textbox inside a gridview and its onkeyup function doesn't seem to work....

Here is my gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <HeaderStyle Width="12%" />
  <HeaderTemplate>
   Advance Detucted
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtAdvanceDeducted" runat="server"  
CssClass="text_box_height_14_width_50" onkeyup="check('this');"></asp:TextBox>
  </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle Width="12%" HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

And my javascript function,

```
var table = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
for (var y = 0; y < table.rows.length; y++) 
{
    for (var x = 0; x < table.rows[y].cells.length; x++) 
     {
        if (table.rows[y].cells[x] == el) 
        {
            alert("Row:" + y + " Cell: " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

When inspected through webdeveloper toolbar i got the error,

`el.parentNode is undefined`

Any suggestion...

`alert(table.rows.length)` gave me 3... But i have 2 rows + one header row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
onkeyup="check('this');" // you are passing a string 'this' to the function.
```

with

```
onkeyup="check(this);" // you are passing a reference of the element.
```

Comment: add some alerts inside the first and second for-loop as well to check

Answer (score 0):

is this being passed as a string rather than an object perhaps is should be:

onkeyup="check(this)

This might be down to asp syntax though. A good way to test is alert or use console.log in firebug to find out what is being passed to the function e.g.

```
console.log(el);
```

or

```
alert(el);
```

as the first line of the function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with ASP: are the quotes around *this* required?

```
check('this') => check(this)
```

regards,
Stijn